# Spécification des couleurs par un groupe nominal et les guillemets

Tags: groupe-nominal, guillemets

Pour désigner une couleur on dispose des noms de couleur : le vert, le noir, le rouge, etc. Il est parfois préférable, si ce n'est strictement une question de choix personnel, de stipuler le mot couleur dans le groupe nominal du nom de couleur et on dit alors « la couleur blanche », « la couleur rose », etc.
Il existe une troisième possibilité qui consiste à combiner non pas le mot « couleur » et l'adjectif de couleur, mais le mot « couleur » et le nom de couleur; ce dernier usage est très courant, cependant correct. Comment se fait-il que l'on ne trouve que des formes telles que « la couleur blanc crême »,  « la couleur blanc nacré », etc. alors que la forme normale devrait être « la couleur « blanc crême » »,  « la couleur « blanc nacré » », etc. Le blanc nacré est une couleur et « blanc nacré » est un groupe nominal. On ne doit pas écrire, normalement, les combinaisons suivantes sans guillemets.

- Le mot « finit » qui est discuté est celui de la seconde phrase.
- La forme verbale « montrant » qu'il faudrait introduire ne convient pas.
- …

Le principe est le même dans les deux cas : un élément est cité comme cas particulier d'un concept générique. Pourquoi existe-t-il cette différence pour les noms de couleur? (Ce n'est d'ailleurs pas une situation qui soit propre uniquement au mot « couleur ».)

Comment: There is no evidence "*couleur blanc*" alone is significantly used. Your interpretation of Google ngrams statistics is flawed. *Couleur blanc cassé* is correct like most if not all similar occurrences.

Comment: Il est vrai que pour le blanc il existe des modificateur,  « cassé »,  « crème », « -gris » et bien d'autres ; il faudrait une recherche plus précise ; cependant, puisque l'on doit considérer « blanc cassé » comme un nom de couleur, il n'y a pas vraiment de différence syntaxique ; aussi, il y a le violet clair comme exemple et il doit y en avoir bien d'autres. Il y a aussi « blanc-gris ».

Comment: Il existe cependant des cas assez nombreux sur le web pour lesquels « noir » est le mot utilisé ; rien que sur une page on trouve les cas suivants : Images de couleur noir, Déco couleur noir, Amazon.fr : couleur noir, Ramette papier couleur noir,  découvrez nos réductions sur l'offre Ramette papier couleur noir sur Cdiscount. https://www.bing.com/search?q=couleur+noir&form=EDGSPH&mkt=fr-fr&httpsmsn=1&refig=ba5e575e5d6f45b18191ea8acefd2a64&sp=2&qs=AS&pq=couleur+noir&sk=AS1&sc=8-12&cvid=ba5e575e5d6f45b18191ea8acefd2a64&cc=FR&setlang=fr-FR

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=couleur+blanc+cr%C3%A8me%2Ccouleur+noir%2Ccouleur+violet+clair%2Ccouleur+blanc-gris%2Ccouleur+blanc+cass%C3%A9%2Ccouleur+blanc&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccouleur%20blanc%20cr%C3%A8me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccouleur%20noir%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccouleur%20violet%20clair%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccouleur%20blanc%20-%20gris%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccouleur%20blanc%20cass%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccouleur%20blanc%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Si les traductions automatiques d'Amazon sont pour toi une référence en terme de syntaxe et de grammaire, je ne peux pas grand chose pour toi. La première pages de ngrams "couleur noir" ne contient quasiment que de faux positifs ou des cas contestables.

Comment: Non, pas Amazone, ce sont des annonces passées par des français et pas une seule mais trois ou quatre ; néanmoins je vais changer la question.

Answer (score 0):

Honnêtement, je pense qu'il s'agit d'un usage abusif, assimilant l'adjectif de couleur à un substantif. L'utilisation du substantif "blanc", par exemple, doit être "le blanc" et non "la couleur blanc" (où blanc est clairement un épithète du substantif "couleur", et doit s'accorder sauf s'il s'agit d'une couleur composée ou d'un objet naturel - et même dans ce dernier cas, il existe cinq exceptions : rose, écarlate, mauve, pourpre et fauve).

Comment: Ce qui est surprenant c'est que l'on trouve ces formes  dans le siècle passé, bien qu'en fréquence négligeable en comparaison avec les formes construites avec l'adjectif; il n'y a que depuis le début de la seconde moitié du XXe siècle que la fréquence approche zéro; si ces formes ont été tolérées, et apparemment elles le sont encore, ne serait-ce qu'une question de négligence dans le travail de publication? Il semble qu'un cas d'erreur de cette sorte sur plus de deux siècles ne soit pas possible. Existerait-il un principe qui aurait été abandonné ou autre explication?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=couleur+noir%2Ccouleur+noire&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccouleur%20noir%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccouleur%20noire%3B%2Cc0 https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=la+couleur+blanc%2Cla+couleur+blanche&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cla%20couleur%20blanc%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cla%20couleur%20blanche%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Dans le premier graphe, vous comparez "couleur blanc" et "couleur blanche". Je remarque qu'une partie importante des occurrences de "couleur blanc" est incluse dans la locution "de couleur blanc", il y a peut-être une piste à creuser ? https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=couleur+blanche%2C+couleur+blanc%2Cde+couleur+blanc&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccouleur%20blanche%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccouleur%20blanc%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cde%20couleur%20blanc%3B%2Cc0

Comment: On trouve un usage varié de modificateurs en plus de « de »; il s'agit bien d'un groupe nominal avec « blanc » comme modificateur de « couleur » mais ça ne nous avance pas plus. Il n'est pas possible de placer ces ngrams dans la  zone de texte des commentaires; il faut utiliser « * couleur blanc » pour obtenir ce multi-ngram.

Comment: 70%des occurrences de "couleur blanc" s'explique par la somme des occurrences de 10 plus fréquentes locutions composées, telles que couleur blanc crème/rosé/jaunâtre/grisâtre/..., cf. https://goo.gl/vJnrCQ .  Je suppose que si l'on listait toutes les locutions de ce genre (et non seulement les dix plus fréquentes), on arriverait plus ou moins à la totalité des occurrences de "couleur blanc".